# Getting garbage input and output over serial connection with microcontroller

Tags: serial, microcontroller

I am trying to connect to a MicroZed board via USB serial with teraterm on Windows 7, and I am running into some issues. I was able to connect to this exact board using minicom on Linux, but I cannot get it to work with Windows. I did also not have to set anything up with Linux, I just used minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0. What would cause this connection problem on Windows?

The attached screenshot is of me typing "ls" once I am connected. So it connects fine, but the output and input are garbled. (see what I typed after the red part is "ls")

[image: Garbage Picture]

Comment: Are the settings correct? Especially the baud rate... If I had to guess, I'd try it by setting it to 9600.

Comment: 9600 results in garbage as well. However, with 9600 I can no longer enter the command "ls" and have it return something (albeit garbled).

Comment: Hmm, I just googled, and found that indeed 115200,8,n,1,n is the recommended setting. Also, taking a better look I can see README text there: that file name seems to be all right. It seems as if the terminal was in a wrong emulation mode... Some characters are right, others are not...

Comment: The input does not seem to be to be garbled; it's the echo back that is trashed.  Instead of the 'ls' command, try typing commands with predictable output, such as 'echo ABCabc123'.  Instead of booting into this board's OS (Linux?), is there a bootloader like U-Boot?

Comment: There may be two issues going on. (1) Some of the characters are two little letters, like `LF`, `VT` and `FF`. VDTs had a **monitor mode**, which caused ASCII control codes (such as `Line Feed`, `Vertical Tab` and `Form Feed`) to be displayed as similar viewable characters instead of performing an action on the cursor.  But although such characters are in your output, there is still cursor actual cursor control going on. (2) Some of the low-case alpha (ASCII 0x61:0x7A) seems to be remapped to the line-drawing characters, which range from 0x81 to 0xDF in IBM PC display codes.

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me as well and closing and re-opening TeraTerm cleared up the issue.  I didn't have to reset the MicroZed.

I suspect that TeraTerm can either get out of sync or automatically change the character encoding on the fly.  I suspect this because I had started the session communicating fine.  I then cat'd a binary file which immediately caused the issue you are seeing.  Once in that state I couldn't get out of it until I closed TeraTerm.